# Sign Up with Google in C# WPF without coding in the client secret

Tags: c#, authentication, google-oauth

I am trying to add the classic sign up with google to my C# WPF application, **without** hardcoding client secret, not even mentioning it in the code. But the topic seem to be convoluted: in 2023 OOB was deprecated, while Desktop option in Google Cloud has no manual redirect uri, creating a deadlock situation. Information is very scarce and unclear for desktop applications, and Google no longer even allows embed browser signups.

The only working direct way is to manually copy authkey google provides into desktop application after successful signup, but it's not an option - it has to be automatic.
Everywhere nowadays is a working proper Google Sign Up button. Sure there must be an easy way or a workaround to implement it? Maybe some way through an endpoint on the server-side API?

All existing tutorials I found involve direct request using both client ID and secret, which works but not an option for an external desktop application. Using OAuth 2.0 leads to manual copying of auth code from the browser windows and I couldn't make the app to read it automatically.

Thanks in advance.